# Java split() a String made out of the String you are splitting with?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

When I compile and run this code:

```
class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin Test");

        String letters = "AAAAAAA"
        String[] broken = letters.split("A");
        for(int i = 0; i < broken.length; i++)
            System.out.println("Item " + i + ": " + broken[i]);

        System.out.println("End Test");
    }
}
```

The output to the console is:

```
Begin Test
End Test
```

Can anyone explain why `split()` works like this? I saw some other questions sort of like this on here, but didn't fully understand why there is no output when splitting a string made entirely out of the character that you are using for `regex`. Why does java handle Strings this way?

Comment: One other note is Java treats /A in a pattern. For example if you set the RegEx Pattern as shown here. http://ideone.com/W1sHLH, you will get another interesting output., Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String.split` discards trailing empty strings.  For example, `"foo,bar,,".split(",")` gets split into `{"foo", "bar"}`.  What you're seeing is a string that consists entirely of the separator, so all the empty splits are "trailing" and get discarded.

You could probably get all those empty strings if you used `letters.split("A", -1)`.  Alternately, [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) doesn't do things like that unless you ask for it: `Splitter.on('A').split(letters)`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I'll accept the answer when I can :P

Answer (score 1):

It is because `"A"` is used as delimiter in split method and since you don't have any other text in your string other than delimiter `"A"` therefore after split you are left with nothing (empty string is not returned in the resulting array).

Answer (score 1):

Since every character in your input is a delimiter, every string found is blank. By default, every trailing blank found is ignored, hence what you're seeing.

However, `split()` comes in two flavours. There is a [second version of the `split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method that accepts another `int` parameter `limit`, which controls the number of times the match is to be applied, but also the behaviour of ignoring trailing blanks.

**If the `limit` parameter is negative, trailing blanks are preserved.**

If you executed this code:

```
String letters = "AAAAAAA";
String[] broken = letters.split("A", -1); // note the -1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(broken));
```

You get this output:

```
{"", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
```

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for more, including examples of how various `limit` values affect behaviour.